# Javascript using Validatious script to toggle required fields based on if Checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, checkbox

I have a checkbox called "purchaseorder". If checked, I'd like to make all of the CC fields not required. However, my script doesn't appear to be working. Any ideas?

The checkbox's name is purchaseorder. The other fields are CC field names. By default, CC fields are required. Only if a customer checks "purchaseorder" should they not be required.

Validatious: http://validatious.org/

```
function ToggleCreditcardpayment() {
  if ($('input[type=checkbox][name=purchaseorder]').is(':checked')) {
    $('#NameOnCard').removeClass('required');
    $('select[name=CreditCardType]').removeClass('required');
    $('select[name=CardExpMonth]').removeClass('required');
    $('select[name=CardExpYear]').removeClass('required');
    $('#CardNumber').removeClass('required');
    $('#CVC').removeClass('required');

    $('#NameOnCard').attr('disabled', true);
    $('select[name=CreditCardType]').attr('disabled', true);
    $('select[name=CardExpMonth]').attr('disabled', true);
    $('select[name=CardExpYear]').attr('disabled', true);
    $('#CardNumber').attr('disabled', true);
    $('#CVC').attr('disabled', true);

    $('#customernumber').addClass('required');
    $('#customernumber').attr('disabled', false);
    $('#payment-method-account .error').removeClass('error');
    $('#payment-method-account ul').remove();
    $('#payment-method-cc .error').removeClass('error');
    $('#payment-method-cc ul').remove();
    ResetValidatious()

  } else {
    $('#NameOnCard').addClass('required');
    $('select[name=CreditCardType]').addClass('required');
    $('select[name=CardExpMonth]').addClass('required');
    $('select[name=CardExpYear]').addClass('required');
    $('#CardNumber').addClass('required');
    $('#CVC').addClass('required');

    $('#NameOnCard').attr('disabled', false);
    $('select[name=CreditCardType]').attr('disabled', false);
    $('select[name=CardExpMonth]').attr('disabled', false);
    $('select[name=CardExpYear]').attr('disabled', false);
    $('#CardNumber').attr('disabled', false);
    $('#CVC').attr('disabled', false);

    $('#customernumber').removeClass('required');
    $('#customernumber').attr('disabled', true);
    $('#payment-method-account .error').removeClass('error');
    $('#payment-method-account ul').remove();
    $('#payment-method-cc .error').removeClass('error');
    $('#payment-method-cc ul').remove();
    ResetValidatious();
  }
}
```

Validation server side:

```
    if(form["purchaseorder"].Value == "yes") 
     {
         UserFormElement elementCustomerNumber = form.GetElement("CustomerNumber");
         if (null != elementCustomerNumber && elementCustomerNumber.GetValue().Trim() == "")
         {
            elementCustomerNumber.AddError("<br/>Customer number is required for pre-approved account.");
         }
         if(form.HasError)
         {
           Redirect("checkout.aspx",true);
           return;
         }

        Payment payment = new Payment(CustomerCtxt);
        payment.PaymentTypeId = DMinSite.Common.DmiProxy.GetInterface<DMinSite.Common.Interfaces.ILookupCommonService>().GetLookupIdByValue(context, DMinSite.Common.Constants.LookupTypeEnum.PaymentType, "PO");
        PaymentPurchaseOrder paymentPurchaseOrder = new PaymentPurchaseOrder(context);
        paymentPurchaseOrder.Amount = cart.CartTotal;
        paymentPurchaseOrder.CustomerNumber = elementCustomerNumber.GetValue().Trim();
        payment.PaymentInfo = paymentPurchaseOrder;

        cart.AddPayment(payment);
    }
    else
    {
        CreditCard card = new CreditCard(CustomerCtxt);
        String note =  form.GetElement("Special").GetValue();
        note = note.Replace('"','\"');
        //order level note
        cart.Note = note;

        UserFormElement elementCCTypeId = form.GetElement("CreditCardType");
        card.CreditCardTypeId = elementCCTypeId.GetValue<int>();

        UserFormElement elementCCNumber = form.GetElement("CardNumber");
        card.Number = elementCCNumber.GetValue();

        UserFormElement elementCCName = form.GetElement("NameOnCard");
        card.NameOnCard = elementCCName.GetValue();

        UserFormElement elementCCExpYear = form.GetElement("CardExpYear");
        UserFormElement elementCCExpMonth = form.GetElement("CardExpMonth");
        if (elementCCExpMonth.GetValue().Trim() == "" || elementCCExpYear.GetValue().Trim() == "")
        {
            elementCCExpMonth.AddError("<br/>The expiration month and/or year is not valid.  Please check your selections and try again.");
        }
        else
        {
            card.ExpirationDate = ControlUtility.ConstructDateTime(
            elementCCExpYear.GetValue<int>(), 
            elementCCExpMonth.GetValue<int>(), 1);
        }

        UserFormElement elementCCCvv2 = form.GetElement("CVC");
        card.Cvv2 = elementCCCvv2.GetValue();

        //check fields
        if (elementCCNumber.GetValue().Trim() == "" || !card.IsValidCreditCardNumber(CustomerCtxt))
        {
            elementCCNumber.AddError("<br/>The credit card number is not valid.  Please check the number and try again.");
        }
        if (elementCCExpYear.GetValue().Trim() + elementCCExpMonth.GetValue().Trim() == "" || card.IsExpired(CustomerCtxt))
        {
            elementCCExpYear.AddError("<br/>The credit card has expired.  Please check the expiration date and try again.");
        }
        if (elementCCCvv2.GetValue().Trim() == "" || !card.IsValidCvv2(CustomerCtxt))
        {
            elementCCCvv2.AddError("<br/>The credit card CVV2 number is not valid.  Please check the CVV2 number and try again.");
        }
        if (elementCCName.GetValue().Trim() == "")
        {
            elementCCName.AddError("<br/>The credit card name is not filled out.  Please check the name and try again.");
        }

        if(form.HasError)
        {
           Redirect("checkout.aspx",true);
           return;
        }

        Payment payment = new Payment(CustomerCtxt);
        payment.PaymentTypeId = Core.GetLookupIdByValue("PaymentType", "CreditCard");
        payment.PaymentInfo = card;
        payment.Amount = cart.CartTotal;        
        cart.AddPayment(payment);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First Option**

```
function ToggleCreditcardpayment() {
  if ($('input[type=checkbox][name=purchaseorder]').is(':checked')) {
  $('input[type=checkbox][name=purchaseorder]').val('Yes');
  //Your other code
  ResetValidatious()

  } else {
  $('input[type=checkbox][name=purchaseorder]').val('No');
  //Your other code
  ResetValidatious();
  }
}
```

**Second Option**
Create a hidden field to store the value depending on if checked or not

```
function ToggleCreditcardpayment() {
    if ($('input[type=checkbox][name=purchaseorderhidden]').is(':checked')) {
    $('input[type=checkbox][name=purchaseorder]').val('Yes');
    //Your other code
    ResetValidatious()

    } else {
    $('input[type=checkbox][name=purchaseorderhidden]').val('No');
    //Your other code
    ResetValidatious();
    }
}
```

Server Side

```
if(form["purchaseorderhidden"].Value == "yes")
{
  //Your validation code
}
else
{
  //Your validation code
}
```

Comment: Ok so, what's happening for me right now that I'm trying your code is that the page will load with the value of "No" because it's not checked by default. However, when I check the box, it does not change from "No" to "Yes".

If I use: <input type="checkbox" name="purchaseorder" id="purchaseorder" checked/>

Then it'll load with "Yes" but will not change to "No" if I uncheck it.

Comment: Also, I'm using the First Option.

Comment: Try $('input[type=checkbox][name=purchaseorder]').prop('value', 'Yes')

Answer (score 0):

Try using this 
    if ($('input[id=purchaseorder]').is(':checked'))
The input of the checkbox, should have and id, that can be the same as the name property.

Comment: Check the jquery version used for the code. Also what is the action is doing right now?

Comment: Using jQuery 1.8.2. Right now, if I check the box and click "Submit Order", it still requires the CC fields.

Comment: On the checked=true road you are disabling the fields, but that do not avoid them to be validated. Is your validation function avoiding disbled fields?

Comment: It seems that if(form["purchaseorder"].Value == "yes") doesnt have a value of yes, please on the server side print the value of form["purchaseorder"].Value to see what it brings. I recommend you that the javascript ToggleCreditcardpayment() should set the purchaseorder checkbox value to yes when is checked and the set it to no when is unchecked.

Comment: What would that code look like to change the value? I have the is checked code already that you gave me. Just need to change value if checked.

Comment: Try the new answer i added